# WP_Error handles errors, but how can I show success with a message?

Tags: plugin-development, admin, errors

My script accesses an api to populate posts. I can add any errors to the WP_Error class, but can I add success messages to a global variable?

Answer (score 1):

you could test for the absence of an error and then display a success message

```
if(!is_wp_error( $thing )) echo "yay!!";
```

Comment: If you use `print` you can shorten it to: `! is_wp_error( $foo ) and print 'win!';` :)